# Union of two time - series

Tags: python, list, time-series

I have two time - series.

1st serie from 1-1-2000 to 31-12-2010

2nd serie from 1-1-2011 to 31-12-2020

I have only two variables: Time and price
I want only one time - serie

I have also ten dataframes. For each dataframe, I have these two series and I want one time-serie for each dataframe (and two series)

```
divisasIndica3=[]
def ls5(di1,di2):
    for a in di1:
        for b in di2:
            di3=di1+di2
            divisasIndica3.append(di3)
```

I don't have one time-serie. I have two series for each element in the list.

It does not merge me to the process of the two series in one

Answer (score 0):

```py
divisasIndica3=[]
def ls5(di1,di2):
    for a in di1:
        for b in di2:
            frames = [a, b]
            result = pd.concat(frames).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)

            divisasIndica3.append(result)
```

I have the solution